# How to convert a 2-d array to 2-d list scala

Tags: scala, matrix, casting

In the middle of learning Scala.

Having a hard time understanding creating an 2-d array then converting it to a 2-d list.

I would think creating an empty `List[List]]` then iterating through the array while converting each array to a list and appending it to a the list.

This throws an error

```
var arr = Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 3))
var ans = List[List[Int]]()
    
for (e <- arr) {
  ans += e.toList
}
```

Then I am given a type mismatch error:

> found: `List[Int]`
>
> required: `Int`

This error doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
val ans = arr.map(_.toList).toList
```

---

If (for whatever reason) you wanted to make your loop run, you'd have to use `:+=`, which would be desugared into `ans = ans :+ e.toList`:

```
for (e <- arr) {
  ans :+= e.toList
}
```

Note, however, that it would be way slower than the `map` (like, wrong asymptotic behavior kind of slower, i.e. really bad), because appending to a list with `:+` requires rebuilding the entire list in every iteration.